# Disable sessions for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I am using Rails 3 and devise. I am building a restful api and I want devise to go through the custom warden strategy that I wrote for each request. But what I am seeing is that it authenticates a user and then uses the session to authenticate subsequent requests.

How can I disable the session entirely? Or get Devise to fully authenticate each time? Or is it just a matter of implementing something in my custom strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure adding this into your strategy would do what you want:

```
Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session {}
Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session {}
```